# É possível fazer relacionamento entre tabelas com chaves armazenadas em coluna JSON?

Tags: mysql, json, join

Possuo duas tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE jtable (id integer, jdata JSON);
INSERT INTO jtable(id, jdata) VALUES(1, '["1","2","3"]');
INSERT INTO jtable(id, jdata) VALUES(2, '["1","3"]');
INSERT INTO jtable(id, jdata) VALUES(3, '["2","3"]');
```

| id | jdata |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["1","2","3"] |
| 2 | ["1","3"] |
| 3 | ["2","3"] |

```
CREATE TABLE informacoes(id integer, value varchar(10));
INSERT INTO informacoes(id, value) VALUES(1,"valor1");
INSERT INTO informacoes(id, value) VALUES(2,"valor2");
INSERT INTO informacoes(id, value) VALUES(3,"valor3");
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | valor1 |
| 2 | valor2 |
| 3 | valor3 |

Na tabela `jtable` possuo uma coluna `jdata` tipo [*JSON* no *MySQL*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).
Essa coluna `jtable.jdata` **sempre conterá** contém um array de inteiros.

### Pergunto:

É possível relacionar esses inteiros na coluna `jtable.jdata` a aos *ids* da tabela *informacoes*(`informacoes.id`), de forma a obter essa estrutura?

| jtable id | informacoes valor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | valor1 |
| 1 | valor2 |
| 1 | valor3 |
| 2 | valor1 |
| 2 | valor3 |
| 3 | valor2 |
| 3 | valor3 |

Eu tentei fazendo o [INNER JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) com o resultado de [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) mas não obtive sucesso:

```
SELECT 
    jtable.jdata,
    informacoes.value,
    JSON_SEARCH(jtable.jdata,'all',informacoes.id)
FROM jtable
INNER JOIN informacoes
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques, apesar de não parecer, mas as tabelas que estou usando são exatamente como coloquei ai, as fiz para tentar chegar no entendimento da query, mas confesso que estou com muita dificuldade.

Comment: Só estou tentando trazer os valores da tabela informacoes que estejam no json da tabela json, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Perfeito @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, no *MySql* é possível relacionar dados de um *documento JSON*<sup>1</sup>  e sim a estrutura de dados pretendida é tangível.

O ambiente do MySql oferece ao seu usuário um [conjunto de funções](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) facilitando a operação com dados [tipificados como JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). Dentre essas funções encontra-se:

[`JSON_TABLE(expr, path COLUMNS (column_list) [AS] alias)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

Que extrai dados de um documento *JSON* e os retorna como uma tabela relacional com as colunas especificadas.

- ***expr:*** Esta é uma expressão contendo os dados `JSON`. Pode ser uma string, uma coluna ou o resultado duma função.
- ***path***: Uma expressão de caminho para identificar um elemento específico em um documento JSON. Para ver em detalhes a sintaxe utilizada leia [Sintaxe de caminho JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax).
- ***COLUMNS***: avalia a origem da linha, encontra valores JSON específicos na origem da linha e retorna esses valores JSON como valores SQL em colunas individuais de uma linha de dados relacionais.
- ***alias*** é um *"apelido"* regido pelas regras usuais para apelidos definidas no manual em [Nomes de objetos do esquema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

Agora conhecendo um pouco mais sobre tabelas e tipo de dados *JSON* o problema se tornou numa consulta [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) trivial solucionada com uso do [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) entre uma *Tabela* e uma *Tabela JSON*.

Usando os dados definidos na pergunta:

```sql
SELECT jt.id AS 'jtable ID', inf.value AS 'Valor' 
FROM jtable AS jt, 
     JSON_TABLE(
        jt.jdata,                                     --Origem do documento JSON.
        '$[*]' COLUMNS( c1 INT PATH '$')              --Declara coluna c1 cujos os elemento são os elemento do array.
     ) AS jsonT
INNER JOIN informacoes as inf                         --Faz a ligação entre os elementos das tabelas jtable e informacoes... 
ON inf.id = jsonT.c1                                  --relacionando informacoes.id a cada elemento obtido na tabela JSON.
ORDER BY jt.id
```

| jtable ID | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | valor1 |
| 1 | valor2 |
| 1 | valor3 |
| 2 | valor1 |
| 2 | valor3 |
| 3 | valor2 |
| 3 | valor3 |

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/8I6Ua3ZsbRTWwaIEbH6pLA?language=mysql)</sup>

<sub>[1] *documento JSON* é termo usado no manual MySql para se referir a um dado cujo o tipo é *JSON*. Esse dado pode vir de string hard coded, de um coluna em uma consulta ou como resultado duma função.</sub>

Comment: FANTÁSTICO! Nem sei como expressar minha gratidão por você ter se dedicado a entender e ainda explicar com clareza na sua resposta. Usar `Json` é, ao meu ver, muito vantajoso e útil em alguns momentos, vou usar muito isso.

Comment: Fico lisonjeado com sua gratidão. Deixo o meu registro que não sou só eu mas todos os usuários ativos do site assim como os moderadores lemos e relemos cada pergunta que avaliamos e tentamos ao máximo dar o prosseguimento e muita gente não entende que o fechamento de uma pergunta não o fim da questão mas o começo de uma busca pelo aprimoramento da mesma, uma pena hoje termos poucos membros atuantes na comunidade. Mas obrigado pela paciência e a persistência.